# Different justification for table caption

Tags: tables, captions

I need get something like this with `caption` package:
[image]

Word "Table 1." in the left with period after number.

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=newline,justification=centering}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Dummy table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    qwe &  & qwe &  & qwe &  & qwe &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  & qwe &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  & qe &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  & q & we &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  & qwe &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  & qe &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new caption label format, and use `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
 \DeclareCaptionFormat{mine}{\raggedright #1.\\\centering #3}%
 \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple, singlelinecheck=off, format=mine}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Dummy table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    qwe & & qwe & & qwe & & qwe & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & qwe & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & qe & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & q & we & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & & qwe & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & & qe & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]